# How can i append pure string into div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this is the requirement. The user can insert tags inside text_field input.

and i got the data from the db like this.

```
var input = "test<br/><iframe src='http://stackoverflow.com/'>" ;
```

I ONLY want to `append` this to PURE string. not tags

but if i append it runs like a tag.

the result i want is just printing

```
test<br/><iframe src='http://stackoverflow.com/'>
```

as a pure string.

Any good solution?

html,

```
<div id="i_want_only_string">

</div>
```

javascript,

```
$(function(){
            var input = "test<br/><iframe src='http://stackoverflow.com/'>" ;
            $("#i_want_only_string").append(input);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fRdLG/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending a [TextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Text) - create it using [document.createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode)

```
$(function () {
    var input = "test<br/><iframe src='http://stackoverflow.com/'>";
    $("#i_want_only_string").append(document.createTextNode(input));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4zwc/)

---

As @BillCriswell noted below if the container `#i_want_only_string` is empty, you can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like

```
$(function () {
    var input = "test<br/><iframe src='http://stackoverflow.com/'>";
    $("#i_want_only_string").text(input);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2pya3/)

Comment: If the element is empty OP can do `$('#i_want_only_string').text(input);` as well.

Comment: @BillCriswell yes.... if the element is empty... since OP used `append()` I assumed it is not

Comment: Reasonable suspicion!

Comment: @BillCriswell thanks... I've updated the text() solution also

Answer (score 0):

You can `append` your container with the `contents` of a new tag that has your input text as its `innerText`

```
$(function () {
    var input = "test<br/><iframe src='http://stackoverflow.com/'>";
    $("#i_want_only_string").append($('<span>').text(input).contents());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/pXHUu/1/)